# Is there a way to raise the backlight on an Android device through the official API?

Tags: android, mobile, backlight, android-1.5-cupcake

What I've read seems to indicate that the only way to do it is to use unofficial APIs that are being locked down in Cupcake (1.5). Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the answer is "not until cupcake".

From [Android Developers Blog: Future-Proofing Your Apps](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/future-proofing-your-apps.html):

> Technique to Avoid, #1: Using Internal APIs
>
> Even though we've always strongly
>   advised against doing so, some
>   developers have chosen to use
>   unsupported or internal APIs. **For
>   instance, many developers are using
>   the internal brightness control** and
>   bluetooth toggle APIs that were
>   present in 1.0 and 1.1. A bug -- which
>   is now fixed in Android 1.5 -- allowed
>   apps to use those APIs without
>   requesting permission. As a result,
>   apps that use those APIs will break on
>   1.5. There are other changes to unsupported APIs in 1.5 besides these,
>   so if you've used internal APIs in
>   your apps, you need to update your
>   apps to stop doing so. Even if they
>   don't break on Android 1.5, there's a
>   good chance they will on some later
>   version. (**There's some good news,
>   though: because "flashlight" apps are
>   so popular, we've added the
>   "screenBrightness" field on the
>   WindowManager.LayoutParams class just
>   for that use case.**)

Comment: actually, you seem to have posted the solution. In you own quote "There's some good news, though: because "flashlight" apps are so popular, we've added the "screenBrightness" field on the WindowManager.LayoutParams class just for that use case.)"

Comment: I know... I stumbled upon it so decided to answer my own question. I also intentionally bolded the relevant passages.